# Recursive Functions Runtime 2^n - 1

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I have the following function `fn(n)`.

```
function fn(n) {
  if (n < 0) return 0;
  if (n < 2) return n;

  return fn(n - 1) + fn(n - 2);
}
```

---

I understand how this code works, but don't how to calculate time complexity for it.

*Let’s do some examples:*

For n = 3, you have 5 function calls. First fn(3), which in turn calls fn(2) and fn(1) and so on.

For n = 4, you have 9 function calls. First fn(4), which in turn calls fn(3) and fn(2) and so on.

[Graphical representation of the 2 examples:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5mO2.png)

---

The leftmost nodes go down in descending order: `fn(4), fn(3), fn(2), fn(1)`, which means that the height of the tree (or the number of levels) on the tree will be `n`.

**The time complexity of this code is `2^n - 1`**. Although, if we count all calls will be just 9 calls for n = 4.

**And the question is how we get `2^n - 1`**? I don't understand

Comment: That's only an upper bound.

Comment: @iBug what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of calculating recursive algorithm's time complexity is using the Recursion Tree Method. For this particular case, we can write T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+2*O(1), where O(1) means constant time, since we have two comparison checks of n values using `if`. The recursion tree would look something like this:

```
1                        n
2             (n-1)               (n-2)
4        (n-2)     (n-3)     (n-3)     (n-4)
8    (n-3)(n-4) (n-4)(n-5) (n-4)(n-5) (n-5)(n-6)
... 
2^i for i-th level
```

Total work done will be the sum of all of the work done in each level, so we can write T(n)=1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + ... = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + ... + 2^i. This is a geometric series which means that the T(n) is equal to (1-2^n)/(1-2) = (1-2^n)/(-1) = 2^n - 1. Because of that the time complexity of the function `fn(n)` is O(2^n).

You could also approach this using Back Substitution method. We know the following:

```
T(0)=1
T(1)=1
T(2)=1
T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+2*O(n)≈2*T(n-1)
```

Substituting `T(n-2)` with `T(n-1)` is allowed. In doing so you will get a higher bound which is still true for `T(n-1)+T(n-2)`.

After the substitution you can also write `T(n-1)=2*T(n-2), T(n-2)=2*T(n-3), ...`
Using these values and substituting them recursively in to the `T(n)` you will get:

```
T(n)=2*2*T(n-2)
    =2*2*2*T(n-3)
    =2*2*2*2*T(n-4)
    =...
    =2^i * T(n-i)
```

From there you can write `n-i=1 => i=n-1` and substitute the `i` value in `T(n)`. You can do this because `T(1)=1` is one of the base conditions.

```
=> T(i)=2^(n-1) * T(n-(n-1))=2^(n-1) * T(n-n+1)=2^(n-1) * T(1)=2^(n-1)
```

This means that the time complexity is O(2^n).